# PyQt4 qTableView Alignment

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

Hoping someone can help me - I've spent a few days searching but haven't had any luck...

I'm using PyQt, and a few qTableViews to display some data - now I want to align this data in the centre.

My code is below - ui_manual_matching.table_unmatched_flights is the qTableView object.

Thanks very much!

Adam

```
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(settings.str_combined_database)
    db.open()
    #CREATE AN SQL STRING TO FILTER BY (I wont bore you with the details)
    flights_table_model = QSqlTableModel()
    flights_table_model.setTable('eg_table')
    flights_table_model.setFilter(str_eg_filter)
    flights_table_model.select()

    ui_manual_matching.table_unmatched_flights.setModel(flights_table_model)
```

'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by subclassing `QSqlTableModel` and overriding the `data()` method. Something like this should do the trick

```
class MySqlModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignCenter
        return QSqlTableModel.data(self,index,role)
```

This will preserve the behaviour of the `QSqlTableModel` you have now, except that when the view asks for the text alignment, your model returns the alignment you want. You can of course choose the alignment by using one of the other flags ([see the Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum)) and even add more logic to set different alignments based on the model index passed into the `data()` method.

P.S. Don't forget to instantiate this new model in your code instead of the one you use now. So replace `flights_table_model = QSqlTableModel()` with `flights_table_model = MySqlModel()`

Comment: Thanks very much! That is great, exactly what I wanted.